# Opening a Material-UI dialog modal from a Header parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui, components

I have a header component separate from a Register dialog modal component. So like a parent an child components. I want to call the Register dialog (child) from the headerlink component (parent)

Here's my headerlinks component:

```
...
import Register from "../Register";
....

export default function HeaderLinks(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
        <Button
          color="transparent"
          className={classes.navLink}
          onClick={handleClickOpen}
        >
          Register
        </Button>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
        <Button
          color="transparent"
          className={classes.navLink}
          
        >
          Log In
        </Button>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
  <Register open={handleClickOpen} onClose={handleClose} />;
}
```

The Register dialog component was simply copied from Material-UI's documentation and removed the button.

```
export default function Register() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Register
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
         ...content...
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the Register button on the headerLink, nothing happens. Not sure what else I'm missing because there are no errors.

Comment: can you post the the code for `Register` component? and what are the `Register` and `CustomizedDialogs` components?

Comment: My bad. `CustomizedDialogs` is the `Register` component. I forgot to rename it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `HeaderLinks`, you've already returned a value on the function so the rest of source code below that will not execute.

```
return (
  <List className={classes.list}>
    ...
  </List>
);
<Register open={handleClickOpen} onClose={handleClose} />; // <-- code will not be reached
```

So just move that inside of the return statement and close them on a single tag because adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Pass down props to `Register`, it does not need an internal state since its `open` prop (according to your design it seems) is to be controlled by `HeaderLinks` component

```
export default function HeaderLinks() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);    
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <List className={classes.list}>
        <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <Button
            color="transparent"
            className={classes.navLink}
            onClick={handleClickOpen}
          >
            Register
          </Button>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <Button color="transparent" className={classes.navLink}>
            Log In
          </Button>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <Register open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
    </>
  );
}

function Register({ open, handleClose }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Register
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>...content...</DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-pine-egsh6]